# Black/White Opacity Mask transparent in Blender 2.8

Tags: shaders

I have two textures: Diffuse and a Black/White opacity map. It's used for the eyebrows. The way the shader is setup the eyebrows are just a completely brown plane. How do I hook up the B/W opacity map to be used for the Alpha of the Principled BSDF?

Here is a screenshot. Obviously putting the image into the alpha is wrong. I tried a mix and transparent shader, but it didn't help.[image]

Comment: Hello. Mixing with a transparent shader should definitely work. Could you please share your blendfile and image file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so I can check what's wrong?

Comment: Your node setup should work properly. Please check that you have the *Blend Mode* set to *Alpha Blend* when using Eevee.

Comment: @RobertGützkow Thank you very much, that solved my issue :)